# Scipy / Numpy : Cholesky while checking if positive definite

Tags: python, scipy, linear-algebra

I am translating a script from Matlab to Python where I have a matrix VarCov and I get the Cholesky decomposition of it.
Sometimes, due to float approximation, a matrix that should be positive devinite (PD) is not, and i have to add a small number to the diagonal.
Here is the Matlab code:

```
[CholeskyUpper,pd] = chol(VarCov);
while pd
    VarCov = VarCov + 0.0001 * eye(size(VarCov,1));
    [CholeskyUpper,pd] = chol(VarCov);
end
```

Matlab is convenient because it can return if a matrix is PD while doing the Cholesky decomposition. It doesn't raise an error while doing so.
It seems that in Python (scipy), it will just return an error.
Is there a way to do something similar to Matlab without having to compute the eigenvalues first ?

Edit: Following sascha's tip I tried this:

```
MyMatrix = np.array([[1,2],[1,2]])
PD = False
while PD == False:
    PD = True
    try:
        MyCholDec = sp.linalg.cholesky(MyMatrix)
    except np.linalg.LinAlgError:
        PD = False
        MyMatrix = MyMatrix + np.eye(2) * 0.001
print("done")
```

Is this the best way ?

Comment: Why don't you just fetch the error and react according to it. From the user perspective everything should behave the same (same core-code used; LAPACK), except that one returns some bool and one throws an error (which is marginally less efficient probably). This is somehow indicated in the [code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.15.1/scipy/linalg/decomp_cholesky.py#L29) -> if some status -> throw error. I'm somewhat sure there is no code-branch visited in python's which is not done in matlab too (early termination).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was investing that right now. Does it invole using a try except ?
What is the proper way to do it? (Sorry started python last week)

Comment: Yes try-except would be my first call. Consider reading the python docs on it. You probably want to be sure what exactly you are catching (which kind of specific errors vs. any error). From someone not doing much low-level-access-like stuff, the non-returning of info in this function (only wrapped in the exception) is sub-optimal imho, but for your use-case it might not matter.

Comment: It seems to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest and easiest method I finally found is to directly use the scipy's lapack function:

```
MyMatrix = np.array([[1,2],[1,2]])        
(MyCholDec ,pd) = sp.linalg.lapack.dpotrf(MyMatrix )
while pd > 0:
     MyMatrix= MyMatrix  + np.eye(2) * 0.01
     (MyCholDec ,pd) = sp.linalg.lapack.dpotrf( MyMatrix )
```

This function works like the Matlab version retunring both the decomposition and an int > 0 if the matrix is not positive definite.